# Force animation to stop (and get to the last position) on click in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, state, statefulwidget

I want to implement `Stories` functionality just like social media platforms. The problem I have is straight forward but I don't know Flutter that much to solve it.

This is the input that I want:-

[image]

This is what I have:-

[image]

As you can see, on click, the loading bar doesn't get full and change. It just keeps its state. And I don't want this. I want it just Like the above gif

This is my code:-

```dart
//.... code about changing the index on tap and other things is right. so no need to put them here.

Positioned(child: Row(children: buildStoryBars(context, widget.options, index),
              ))
```

And this is the function that does the work:-

```dart
List<StoryBar> buildStoryBars(
    BuildContext context, StoryOptions options, int index) {
  final screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
  List<StoryBar> data = [];
  double width;

width = screenWidth / options.stories.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < options.stories.length; i++) {
      data.add(
        StoryBar(
            storyType: StoryMediaType.image,
            duration: options.duration,
            seen: i < index ? true : false,
            shouldAnimate: i <= index ? true : false,
            width: width),
      );
    }
return data;
}
```

And this is my widget for showing the animated bars:-

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:percent_indicator/linear_percent_indicator.dart';

import '../utils/enums.dart';

class StoryBar extends StatelessWidget {
  final StoryMediaType storyType;
  final Duration duration;
  final bool seen;
  final bool shouldAnimate;
  final double width;
  const StoryBar(
      {Key? key,
      required this.storyType,
      required this.duration,
      required this.seen,
      required this.width,
      required this.shouldAnimate})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LinearPercentIndicator(
      width: width,
      lineHeight: 10.0,
      percent: shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.0,
      linearStrokeCap: LinearStrokeCap.roundAll,
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
      progressColor: Colors.white,
      isRTL: true,
      animation: seen == false ? true : false,
      animationDuration: duration.inMilliseconds,
      addAutomaticKeepAlive: false,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5.0),
    );
  }
}
```

So is there a way to achieve the desired output above just like Facebook?
I have used everything I know about Flutter and programming :(
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried `animateTo()` method of AnimationController?

Comment: @Mayank, Doesn't work in this case

Answer (score 0):

Add a new condition to set all previous items to a value of 1.0 if they have been "seen"

```
percent: seen ? 1.0 : shouldAnimate ? 1.0 : 0.0
```

The issue here is that you are disabling the animation explicitly when a a story is skipped

```
animation: seen == false ? true : false
```

But that will stop and keep the status of the progress indicator (if it was 0.2 it will stay that way) and the above solution is to set all items that are considered as "seen" to a value of 1.0